# Translate and Rotate specific node in ARSCNView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arkit

I am adding Nodes in ARSCNView as child nodes and clone nodes depending on what i choose from the menu. The object is placed where I tap on the screen. How to translate and scale the specific node.

Answer (score 3):

Use [transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407964-transform) attribute of `SCNNode` for that:

> The transformation is the combination of the node’s  rotation ,
> position , and  scale properties. The default transformation is
> SCNMatrix4Identity.
>
> When you set the value of this property, the
> node’s rotation, orientation, eulerAngles, position, and scale
> properties automatically change to match the new transform, and vice
> versa. SceneKit can perform this conversion only if the transform you
> provide is a combination of rotation, translation, and scale
> operations. If you set the value of this property to a skew
> transformation or to a nonaffine transformation, the values of these
> properties become undefined. Setting a new value for any of these
> properties causes SceneKit to compute a new transformation, discarding
> any skew or nonaffine operations in the original transformation. You
> can animate changes to this property’s value. See Animating SceneKit
> Content.

Or you can use:

- [position](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408026-position),
- [rotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408034-rotation),
- [eulerAngles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407980-eulerangles),
- [orientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408048-orientation),
- [scale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408050-scale)

Comment: I have to do it through gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You can look how Apple's sample code are doing same thing [here](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip)

With its VirtualObjectManager and recognizers for Scale/Translate.

Comment: I am using Objective C language and Apple's code is in swift.

Comment: by reading the code you can get general idea + method names are pretty same. if there's something you don't understand, feel free to ask here.

Comment: When I tap on screen, the objects appear bigger sometimes. Seems to be close to camera. How to fix it?